# FFMPEG ignores encoding level parameter

Tags: rust, ffmpeg, h.264, v4l2

I need to be able to encode video to a specific profile-level-id in accordance to a negotiated session via WebRTC. I can readily change the profile via code, however, I have not been able to change the [level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels). I am using the hardware encoder on the RaspberryPi 4, which uses a BCM2835 via Video4Linux2 drivers. By default, the driver is leaving the encoding level set to level 4, which I can verify by taking a sample I am generating with the encoder and running the command `mediainfo sample.h264 | grep profile` over the sample. Everything I have tried has been setting the level back to the default level 4 encoding.

The code below is `ffmpeg-next`, an ffmpeg wrapper in rust. All the commands can be traced back to C api calls for ffmpeg.

```rs
pub fn create_encoder() -> ffmpeg_next::codec::encoder::video::Video {
    let codec = ffmpeg_next::encoder::find_by_name("h264_v4l2m2m").unwrap();
    let ctx = new_context_from(codec).encoder();
    let mut ctx = ctx.video().unwrap();
    ctx.set_width(1280);
    ctx.set_height(720);
    ctx.set_format(ffmpeg_next::format::pixel::Pixel::YUV420P);
    let fps = ffmpeg_next::Rational::new(30, 1);
    let tb = fps.invert();
    ctx.set_frame_rate(Some(fps));
    ctx.set_time_base(tb);
    ctx.set_bit_rate(4_000_000);
    ctx.set_max_bit_rate(4_000_000);
    ctx.set_aspect_ratio(ffmpeg_next::util::rational::Rational(16, 9));
    ctx.set_flags(ffmpeg_next::codec::Flags::GLOBAL_HEADER);
    ctx.set_gop(0);
    ctx.set_max_b_frames(0);

    // ----- Below here is my attempt to set profile and level -----
    // Below modifies `compression_level`, but tried it as well just in case
    ctx.set_compression(Some(9)); // Does not work (tried 9 & 31)
    unsafe {
        let mut p = ctx.as_mut_ptr();
        (*p).profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH; // <-- Changing this will change the profile (works)
        (*p).level = 9; // Does not work (tried 9 & 31)
    }

    // Does not work (Errors with OptionNotFound)
    if let Err(e) = video_opt_set(&mut ctx, "level", "9", 0) {
        log::warn!("Could not set the level: {:?}", e);
    }

    // Does not work (Errors with OptionNotFound)
    if let Err(e) = video_opt_set(&mut ctx, "h264_level", "9", 0) {
        log::warn!("Could not set the h264_level: {:?}", e);
    }

    // This is an attempt to make an AVDictionary for avcodec_open2
    // (tried 9, 31, & 3.1)
    let settings = make_avdict("level=9,h264_level=9").unwrap();
    ctx.open_with(settings).unwrap().0
}

/// Modified from:
/// https://github.com/zmwangx/rust-ffmpeg/blob/master/examples/transcode-x264.rs#L154
pub fn make_avdict<'a, S: AsRef<str>>(s: S) -> Option<Dictionary<'a>> {
    let s = s.as_ref();
    let mut dict = Dictionary::new();
    for keyval in s.split_terminator(',') {
        let tokens: Vec<&str> = keyval.split('=').collect();
        match tokens[..] {
            [key, val] => dict.set(key, val),
            _ => return None,
        }
    }
    Some(dict)
}

/// Helper function to wrap `av_opt_set` and properly return an exception on failures
pub fn video_opt_set(video: &mut Video, key: &str, value: &str, search: i32) -> Result<(), OptError> {
    let err = unsafe {
        av_opt_set(
            (*video.as_ptr()).priv_data,
            key.as_ptr(),
            value.as_ptr(),
            search,
        )
    };
    match err {
        0 => Ok(()),
        AVERROR_OPTION_NOT_FOUND => Err(OptError::OptionNotFound),
        -34 => Err(OptError::RangeError),
        -22 => Err(OptError::Invalid),
        _ => panic!("Not a valid error code")
    }
}
```

The V4L2 hardware encoder is device 11 (`/dev/video11`). I can use `v4l-ctl` to interrogate the options it has available:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d 11 -l

Codec Controls

                 video_b_frames 0x009909ca (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=update
                 video_gop_size 0x009909cb (int)    : min=0 max=2147483647 step=1 default=60 value=60
             video_bitrate_mode 0x009909ce (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0 flags=update
                  video_bitrate 0x009909cf (int)    : min=25000 max=25000000 step=25000 default=10000000 value=10000000
           sequence_header_mode 0x009909d8 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=1 value=1
         repeat_sequence_header 0x009909e2 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                force_key_frame 0x009909e5 (button) : flags=write-only, execute-on-write
          h264_minimum_qp_value 0x00990a61 (int)    : min=0 max=51 step=1 default=20 value=20
          h264_maximum_qp_value 0x00990a62 (int)    : min=0 max=51 step=1 default=51 value=51
            h264_i_frame_period 0x00990a66 (int)    : min=0 max=2147483647 step=1 default=60 value=60
                     h264_level 0x00990a67 (menu)   : min=0 max=15 default=11 value=11
                   h264_profile 0x00990a6b (menu)   : min=0 max=4 default=4 value=4
```

And specifically looking at profile and level I have the following options provided by V4L2:

```
                     h264_level 0x00990a67 (menu)   : min=0 max=15 default=11 value=11
                                0: 1
                                1: 1b
                                2: 1.1
                                3: 1.2
                                4: 1.3
                                5: 2
                                6: 2.1
                                7: 2.2
                                8: 3
                                9: 3.1
                                10: 3.2
                                11: 4
                                12: 4.1
                                13: 4.2
                                14: 5
                                15: 5.1
                   h264_profile 0x00990a6b (menu)   : min=0 max=4 default=4 value=4
                                0: Baseline
                                1: Constrained Baseline
                                2: Main
                                4: High
```

I have even tried overwriting the default for V4L with the command `v4l2-ctl -d 11 --set-ctrl=h264_level=9`. But this does nothing. It doesn't error, which would be the case where I would enter a setting that doesn't exist such as `h264_levelx`. Also, if I try to change it to something like `999`, the command errors out with "Numerical result out of range". So it understands the parameter I am trying to change and has a grasp on what values it can modify to. But instead of seeing any changes, the command simply executes without error and applies no lasting changes.